# Web Part iframe HTML5 animation does not play

Tags: content-editor-web-part, html5

I'm starting to play with Google Web Designer to create animations of industrial machine sequences. They work fine when the resultant HTML file is opened directly in the browser.

I'm now testing my ability to load these into our Sharepoint intranet.

- I upload the HTML file into the documents folder.
- I create a web part and select *Media and Content* followed by *Content Editor*.
- In the *Content Editor* I paste in the URL and set the section height.
- The animation runs while the editor is open.
- I save the changes and the HTML appears to embed OK but the animation doesn't run.

I'm not sure which version of Sharepoint we're running but I'd expect it to be five or six years old.

Has anyone a suggestion to get this to work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to let your SharePoint site know that you trust the site used via an iFrame. In order to do it:

- Browse to the root site of your site collection.
- Click **Settings** > click **Site Settings**. If you don't see **Site settings**, click **Site information** and then click View all site settings.
- On the **Site settings** page, under **Site Collection Administration**, click **HTML Field Security**.

[image]

- Select **Allow contributors to insert iframes only from the following domains** to add a web domain to a list of domains whose content can be displayed in iframes in the site collection. To remove a website from the list, select it, and then click Remove.

[image]

- Click OK